# How to get the checked items listed in a Qt QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, checked, qlistwidget

I've populated a QListWidget with a list of items and added a check box leaving everything unchecked.

```
for td in root.iter('testdata'):
    test_data = td.get('ins')
    item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(test_data, self.listWidgetLabels)
    item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
    item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
```

The user then clicks a few of the items in the QListItem and clicks a 'Generate File' button on the gui.

```
self.pushButtonGenerateFile.clicked.connect(self.generate_file)
```

I want to get a list of all the checked QListItems.

```
def generate_driver(self):
    test = self.listWidgetLabels.selectedItems()
    items = []
    checked_items = []
    for index in range(self.listWidgetLabels.count()):
        items.append(self.listWidgetLabels.item(index))

        for x in self.listWidgetLabels.selectedItems():
            checked.append(x.text())
    for i in checked:
        print("Checked Items: {0}".format(i))
```

What is above gets the selectedItem in the list. I've tried get checkState(), getChecked(), but they don't exist for QListWidget items.

Any clues are much appreciated.

Thanks,

John.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to check if `checkState` is actually `Qt.Checked`:

```
for index in range(self.listWidgetLabels.count()):
    if self.listWidgetLabels.item(index).checkState() == Qt.Checked:
        checked_items.append(self.listWidgetLabels.item(index).text())
```